# Tag on UItextField received EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios4, tags, uitextfield, exc-bad-access

HI,
Im creating a UItextField trying to get the tag when editing did end. i'm receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS when the showTag is called  :

```
UITextField *text = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195.0, (m*30)+1 , 70.0, 23.0)] autorelease];
    text.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    text.tag=MyintValue;

    [text addTarget:self action:@selector(showTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
    [scrollView addSubview:text];




 - (IBAction)showTag:(UITextField* )sender{ 
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", =[sender tag] ] message:@”" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

}

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sender tag] ]
```

tag is int value so

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@d",[sender tag] ]
```

...i tried this...got no problem...worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [sender tag]]
```

the tag is an int. If you use %@, it is interpreted as a pointer and trying to access that memory address (5 or 22 or whatever the int value of the tag is) fails because it's not valid, hence the crash.